# Detecting 3G network connection with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I try to detect network connection on meteor.

I use Meteor.status(), It's detect the connection if I turn off /on wifi
But with 3G H+ network it's do not detect that the device is connected to internet ( meteor.status().connection return false)

I wonder if there is a way to make it work for 3G connection, or maybe I need to detect it with pure js?

I saw that The Verso App (made with meteor) detect it, anyone have clue about how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is on "localhost", it is normal Meteor.status().connected return false when you're on 3G. 3G is not on your  local network.

I just spent 30 minutes just to understand why.

Comment: oh really? can you explain me why?

Comment: because localhost is 127.0.0.1 in local network. And your 3G connection is in "internet network".